# Loading .obj file in OpenGL in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, linker

In which directory should I store the .obj models in Visual Studio 2010?

I am using the [OpenGL Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Mathematics) (GLM) library to use them in OpenGL, and when I try to load the object it shows

> Error11error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glmReadOBJ referenced in function _SDL_main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to have no relation to your actual problem. You're not getting this error when you "try to load the object"; this is a *linker* error. You get this when you try to compile and link your code. It has nothing to do with where the ".obj" files are stored, because you haven't created a functioning executable yet.

The linker error is telling you that you probably did not link to the GL Mesh library correctly.

Comment: ohh.... i downloaded the glm library from the site http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/
but the folder just contains .h and .cpp files...
i included the .h files in my project ...
but how do i create the links when there are no .lib files ?

Comment: @adityap174: You build the library; that's what a source code distribution is for. I checked the download and sadly it doesn't come with a VS-compatible build system. So you'll have to try to figure out how the makefile-based build works and replicate it in VS2010..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...
m new to this....
i compiled it using dev cpp
now it's working properly
thanx :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is resolved already but, for future reference if you look at the readme.txt that comes with GLM the "GLM Usage" section has the following:

```
    GLM is a header only library, there is nothing to build, just include it.
    #include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

So if you are using VStudio you'll just need to add the directory containing the GLM headers as a "Additional Include Directory" (Right Click the Project, Select Properties, Select "General" under "C/C++", should be top entry.) Good deal.

Comment: Actually i was not able to use it directly by including it. It used to give some linkage errors. Don't remember now. It was 2 years ago. I compiled it using Dev Cpp and it started working properly. Anyways thanks for the tip

Comment: this is for the regular distribution of glm. he's talking about the glm extension to read obj files, which has binaries